# Проблема с селектором CSS

Tags: html, css

Столкнулся с проблемой псевдокласса CSS `:nth-of-type(3n)`

Я ожидал что конструкция `.item-container:nth-of-type(3n)` Будет применена к каждому третьему блоку с классом `item-container`. Но как видно на скриншоте ниже, этот стиль применился к пятому элементу. Никаких вложенных элементов с этим классом нет.

Почему браузер считает блок `<div class='clearfix'></div>` вместе с `<div class='item-container'></div>`?

Как правильно указать селектор для каждого третьего элемента с классом `item-container`?

Живой пример:

```css
.item-container:nth-of-type(3n) {
    float: right!important;
    margin-right: 0;
}
.item-container {
float:left;
width: 150px;
padding: 9px;
margin-right: 15px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
border: 1px #d7d7d7 solid;
border-radius: 3px;
}
.clearfix {clear:both;}
```

```html
<div style="margin: 15px">
 <p id="mainColumnTitle">Товары для Fly Ezzy Trendy</p>
 <div class="item-container left">
   <div class="img"></div>
   <p class="item-name"><a href="/site/item?partid=78">Динамик</a></p>
   <div class="left"><b>200</b> руб</div>
   <div class="instock right">в наличии</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item-container left">
   <div class="img"></div>
   <p class="item-name"><a href="/site/item?partid=78">Динамик</a></p>
   <div class="left"><b>200</b> руб</div>
   <div class="instock right">в наличии</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item-container left">
   <div class="img"></div>
   <p class="item-name"><a href="/site/item?partid=78">Динамик</a></p>
   <div class="left"><b>200</b> руб</div>
   <div class="instock right">в наличии</div>
 </div>
 <div class='clearfix'></div>
 <div class="item-container left">
   <div class="img"></div>
   <p class="item-name"><a href="/site/item?partid=78">Динамик</a></p>
   <div class="left"><b>200</b> руб</div>
   <div class="instock right">в наличии</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item-container left">
   <div class="img"></div>
   <p class="item-name"><a href="/site/item?partid=78">Динамик</a></p>
   <div class="left"><b>200</b> руб</div>
   <div class="instock right">в наличии</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item-container left">
   <div class="img"></div>
   <p class="item-name"><a href="/site/item?partid=78">Динамик</a></p>
   <div class="left"><b>200</b> руб</div>
   <div class="instock right">в наличии</div>
 </div>
 <div class='clearfix'></div>
 <div class="item-container left">
   <div class="img"></div>
   <p class="item-name"><a href="/site/item?partid=78">Динамик</a></p>
   <div class="left"><b>200</b> руб</div>
   <div class="instock right">в наличии</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item-container left">
   <div class="img"></div>
   <p class="item-name"><a href="/site/item?partid=78">Динамик</a></p>
   <div class="left"><b>200</b> руб</div>
   <div class="instock right">в наличии</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению, вы неверно истолковали смысл псевдо-класса `:nth-of-type`.

Он работает только с *типом* элемента (т.е. `p`, `div`, `a`, и т.д.), но не с *классом* элемента. В CSS не существует псевдо-класса `:nth-of-class`, который мог бы выполнить эту задачу. Поэтому в вашем случае браузер перебирает не блоки с классом `"item-container"`, а просто элементы с типом `div`.

Чтобы решить вашу проблему, используйте другой тип для элементов с классом `"clearfix"`, например, `<span>` или `<br>`.

**ДЕМО:** http://jsfiddle.net/fkwzLm8j/2/

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `nth-child`.
Следуя из названия `nth-of-type` будет использовать тип элемента (имя тэга).
Прочитайте вполне доступную [статью](http://habrahabr.ru/post/119139/).